# Anychart zooming on non-map chart types

Tags: anychart

Working on a project using AnyChart and I'm unable to get zooming to work on any non-map type charts (specifically working with scatterplot.) It doesn't seem like they support anything other than a scroll bar as far as zooming goes for charts like scatterplot.

Does anyone have any clever solutions to be able to add zooming to these charts?

Comment: Many chart types support vertical and horizontal scroll bars which implement zooming and scrolling by dragging a scrollbar. Do you need any other tool for zooming? Do you want to zoom with mouse-wheel?

Comment: That's what I was looking for, being able to zoom with the mouse-wheel or by drag selecting a region. I was able to accomplish both on a map chart type but not on scatterplot.

Comment: Unfortunately, now we can't suggest a solution with mouse-wheel zooming and dragging plot by mouse. But you can add vertical and horizontal scrollbars for the scatter plot. Here is the sample - https://playground.anychart.com/PFK9l8m5/0